# PHP linter for undefined variables/associative keys

Tags: php, static-analysis

We are looking for a PHP linter, and we are chasing a particular problem that's causing E_NOTICE's, a lot of them:

```
    if($undef_variable)...
    if($assoc['undef_key'])...
    $undef_variable?...:...
    $assoc['undef_key']?...:...
```

Functionally, the code works perfectly so if the tools was also able to replace on-the-fly such occurences with i.e.

```
   if($undef_variable??null)
```

That would be a huge help.
Some of the code is in templates that are in included with some pre-set variables (always the same). So ideally the tool would also allow configuring some available global-namespace variables.
The tool should absolutely understand PHP7 syntax, especially anonymous functions.

At a minimum, we need to generate a list of every occurence where a variable is used as a boolean condition and is not defined in the same scope, and every occurence where an array key is used as a boolean condition.

Answer (score 3):

Phpcs- PhpCodeSniffer can be used for that.  You need to configure a rule for that. Find it here - [Phpcs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

Check this rule - 
https://github.com/sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis

If you use PhpStorm, it has an option in Inspections. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-undefined-variable.html